# While sharing one image in linkedin, Oops ! error showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linkedin-api

While I am sharing any url in linkedin from my website, its working fine from QA host URL, but does n't work from local host/any other url.

Error:

> Oops! Its not you its us, Give another try, please.

code for sharing url is common for both.
is there anything from linked in side to authenticate my host or anything else?

I expect its should show share page from localhost too.

For example: https://test.com/UserProfile/244/2321454

Comment: what link are you trying to share?

Comment: for example : https://test.com/UserProfile/244/2321454 
it is just profile of an user i want to share in linkedin.

Answer (score 0):

Your link works perfectly fine for me.  This...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2FUserProfile%2F244%2F2321454
```

Shows me this...

[image]

URL formatting: [**Official Microsoft.com Linkedin Share Plugin Documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)

Adding prefilled parameters: **[LinkedIn Developer Docs: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn](http://LinkedIn%20Developer%20Docs:%20Making%20Your%20Website%20Shareable%20on%20LinkedIn.)**.